# Request twitter oauth2 token endpoint using python

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, python-requests, twitter-oauth

I am following these instructions https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token to generate an access and refresh token for the twitter api.

I have a flask app running wit an endpoint on `http://localhost:5000` on the route `/` it redirects to `https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize`. After accepting the consent form the user is redirect to my route `http://localhost:500/redirect`. In `request.args` I get the code needed to create my access and refresh token.

```
@app.route("/redirect", methods=["GET"])
def redir():
    args = request.args
    auth_str=str(base64.b64encode(b"{0}:{1}".format(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)))
    r = requests.post(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token",
        params=dict(
            code=args["code"],
            grant_type="authorization_code",
            redirect_uri="http://localhost:5000/redirect",
            code_verifier="challenge",
        ),
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": f'Basic {auth_str}',
        },
    )

    return r.text
```

The response `r` just contains the info `This page is down` but no further info on how to debug the problem an receive the tokens.

Comment: Have you tried sending the same request via curl or Postman? It sounds really strange.

Comment: Yes i tried both. After receiving the code I copied the curl example from the docs adapted the parameters and sent it. I did the same with postman, with the same effect.